# htaccess - Rewrite domain and exclude folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, cdn

overwriting the image links to cdn or subdomain

need to link the type `http://example.com/folders1/folders2/FoldersAndAnyLinkToImage.jpg or png` rewrite the link the `http://cdn.example.com/FoldersAndAnyLinkToImage.jpg` 
that is, eliminate it, these two folders `/folders1/folders2` from the url

advance thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+/(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|png))$ http://cdn.example.com/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but is it possible to specify a specific folder?

Comment: Yes sure, just change rule to: `RewriteRule ^folders1/folders2/(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|png))$ http://cdn.example.com/$1 [L,NC,R=302]`